PDF compression technique
I was trying to merge some PDF on Laravel 10. If there are any other type of file I am converting them into PDF and merging. Sometimes, for some PDFs, I get this kind of error:

This PDF document probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI. (See https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser for more details)

Is there any way to solve this? Or any way to get PDF file compression  method?
This is my function to merge PDFs.
function mergePDFs(array $pdfPaths, $fileName, $fullPublicPath = false)
{
    if ( count($pdfPaths) <= 0 ) return null;

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 900);

    $pdfTempFiles = [];
    $oMerger = PDFMerger::init();

    try {
        foreach ($pdfPaths as $pdfPath) {
            $tempPath = 'uploads/temp/' . \Illuminate\Support\Str::uuid().'.pdf';

            $extension = getExtension($pdfPath);

            $pdfPath = public_path(substring($pdfPath, "uploads"));

            if ( $extension == 'pdf' ) {
                $oMerger->addPDF($pdfPath, 'all');
                continue;
            }

            if ( isDocType($pdfPath) ){
                if ( $extension == 'xlsx' || $extension == 'xls' ){
                    $path = xlsToPDF($pdfPath, $tempPath);
                    $oMerger->addPDF($path, 'all');
                    $pdfTempFiles[] = $path;
                } else {
                    if ( $extension == 'doc' ){
                        $newPath = public_path('uploads/temp/' . \Illuminate\Support\Str::uuid().'.docx');
                        $pdfPath = docToDocx($pdfPath, $newPath);
                        $pdfTempFiles[] = $newPath;
                    }

                    $path = docxToPDF($pdfPath, $tempPath);
                    $oMerger->addPDF($path, 'all');
                    $pdfTempFiles[] = $path;
                }
            } else {
                if ( $extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png' ){
                    $path = imageToPDF($pdfPath, $tempPath);
                    $oMerger->addPDF($path, 'all');
                    $pdfTempFiles[] = $path;
                } elseif ( $extension == 'webp' ){
                    $path = convertWebpToPdf($pdfPath, $fileName);
                    $oMerger->addPDF($path, 'all');
                    $pdfTempFiles[] = $path;
                } elseif ( $extension == 'bmp' ){
                    $path = convertBmpToPdf($pdfPath, $fileName);
                    $oMerger->addPDF($path, 'all');
                    $pdfTempFiles[] = $path;
                }
            }
        }

        $oMerger->merge();
        $oMerger->save($fileName);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    foreach ($pdfTempFiles as $pdfTempFile) {
        unlink($pdfTempFile);
    }

    return ($fullPublicPath) ? $fileName : url(substring($fileName, 'uploads'));
}


"Or any way to get PDF file compression method ?" - Follow the link you posted: With this seperate parser, as a commercial add-on, you're up to date and FPDI will be able to handle PDF documents which uses this compression feature without a problem.

One of the ways, print the PDF files (from the client side) so that the resulting PDF are not compressed / encrypted and then re-try

Thanks guys . I solved this using "qpdf" .  I can merge all the PDF . working almost all Compression method .
